# Oozie + YARN : getting connection failure exception

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, oozie, mapr

In our application, we want that at a time only one oozie workflow should be running.
We are facing issue where connection with first workflow break, and due to this second workflow starts. On YARN first workflow is still running.

We getting following error message:

```
E0603 : E0603: SQL error in operation, The last packet successfully received from the server was 94,669,212 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 94,669,212 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
        at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient.handleError(OozieClient.java:628)
        at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient$JobInfo.call(OozieClient.java:980)
        at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient$JobInfo.call(OozieClient.java:964)
        at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient$ClientCallable.call(OozieClient.java:576)
        at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient.getJobInfo(OozieClient.java:1055)
        at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient.getJobInfo(OozieClient.java:1033
```

)

Not sure where to set the 'wait_timeout'/'autoReconnect' property.
Is it set at each action level in the oozie workflow xml?

Regards
Anuj Mehra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MapR Technical Support Engineer, Prakhar Verma, you can ignore these exceptions in the code which are harmless.  Please re-write your java code.